# 'This' is undefined in typescript even using arrow func in a promise

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I receive the 'catch' callback, 'this' is undefined, even using arrow funcitions. Any ideas?

```
private all(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    EntityRepository.getRepositoty(req.params.etName).then(repo => {

        ...

    }).catch((err) => {
        this.handleError(res, err); // here I get undefined.
    });
}
```

**how the all func is called.**

It's called based on a Express route.

Added mathod `bind` as @jfriend00 suggested.

```
constructor() {
    // Connect to database.
    DataAccess.connect();

    // Starts configuring routes for api
    this.router = Router();

    // Bad request due to absence of entity type.
    this.router.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.statusMessage = SysMsgs.error.noEntityTypeSpecified.message;
        res.send();
    });

    // Added method 'bind'.
    this.router.get(this.routeBase, this.all.bind(this));
    this.router.get(this.routeBase + "/:id", this.findOne.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: This question requires a lot more information, share how you invoked this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With arrow functions, `this` will retain the value it had in the scope prior to the arrow function call. In your case, that means it will have whatever value `this` was at the beginning of your `all` function.  So, that value of `this` depends upon how the `all` function is called.

And, based on your `this.router.get()` where you specify `this.all` as the callback, that means that `this` inside of `all` will be set to whatever Express sets it to when it calls that callback.  And, that is `undefined`.

You can fix your issue by using `.bind()`.

```
 this.router.get(this.routeBase, this.all.bind(this));
```

That will assure that the appropriate `this` is set when `.all()` runs.  And, then your `arrow` function inside of `all()` will use that value of `this`.

Note: you will need to use `.bind()` for any method you are passing as a callback where you expect `this` to be the object inside the callback.  When you pass something like `this.all`, the value of `this` is lost and only a reference to the method is passed.   The caller then calls that method as a normal function with no object binding.  You use `.bind()` to take control of that yourself.  `.bind()` essentially creates a little stub function that reattaches the appropriate `this` pointer by calling your method using it.

---

You could also make your own wrapper arrow function for it:

```
 this.router.get(this.routeBase, (req, res) => this.all(req, res));
```

which as Saravana points out will retain TypeScript type checking.

Comment: I tried it, but I still getting 'undefined'. See my chenges in the question's code.

Comment: I just put a breakpoint on the line where the error occurred and the vs code showed me 'undefined' and I came back here to tell you. But it works perfectly when I continue the program! (I think it's a vs code bug, maybe.). Thanks!!!

Comment: There is one caveat with using `bind` in TypeScript. I have explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

While @jfriend00's answer covers the problem with your code and there is nothing wrong with using `bind` in JavaScript, there is one little problem when you use `bind` in TypeScript though. The type signature for `bind` is:

```
bind(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;
```

Notice that `bind` returns `any` meaning any type checks on the returned function is turned off, which leads to subtle bugs. Take the following for example:

```
// Assume the definition for `router.get` is something similar to this:
get(routeBase: string, callback: (req: Request, resp: Response) => void)

// ... and in the place you are calling it
private all(param: number): void {
}

this.route.get(this.routeBase, this.all.bind(this)); 
// No compiler error, but `all` and the callback parameter expected by `route.get` don't match!
```

If you would like to keep type checking you can use something like below instead of `bind`:

```
this.route.get((req, resp) => this.all(req, resp));
```

See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212

Comment: Great answer too. Thanks, it's good to see the pros and cons of this two ways.